# Gradle 'configuring projects' never ends

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Clean install of Android Studio 0.8. I create a new project with a blank activity and it will not let me run the app because there appears to be a gradle task still running. All it says is "Gradle: Configure projects" in the status bar of Android Studio and it just sits there. I'm not sure what's wrong but I've been trying to get an android dev environment setup on a couple of machines now and consistently hit this same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio stuck when creating new Project on Gradle: Configure Project or Gradle: Resolve Dependencies ':classpath:'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621678/android-studio-stuck-when-creating-new-project-on-gradle-configure-project-or-g)