# Android Studio stuck when creating new Project on Gradle: Configure Project or Gradle: Resolve Dependencies ':classpath:'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Using the new project wizard to create a new Android application, The IDE gets stuck before I can even see the Code files. After trying to create many types of projects, It tells me that it is building and the IDE only shows a Loading box that says either:

```
Gradle: Configure Project
```

or

```
Gradle: Resolve Dependencies ':classpath:'
```

I went out to lunch and when I came back I saw:

Error:Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.12.1/builder-model-0.12.1.jar'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bintray has experienced momentary timeouts yesterday due to a change to one of the cluster nodes in Dallas.
It looks like you've happened to hit that exact node at that exact time.

The issue has been sorted out after a couple of minutes, so there is no real need to change anything on your side.

Actually, keeping `jcenter()` in your script is preferable since it's a super-set of Maven Central.

Comment: Noted! However, In my case, I tried for a few hours and had to Develop a demo for tomorrow. It was a last ditch effort. I'll change it back, thanks.

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same issue. I'm behind a proxy, I've setup HTTP proxy for gradle as well, but still the issue persists:
`Error:Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project</a>`

Comment: Looks like your proxy is misbehaving. Can you get to https://jcenter.bintray.com in the browser?

Answer (score 16):

In order to solve it, I went to `File -> Project Structure -> Project` and changed:

Android Plugin Repository and Default Plugin Repository  from their default values of

`jCenter()`

to

`mavenCentral`

Comment: Why would you switch from jCenter() back to mavenCentral()?

Comment: Solved the same problem in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and was able to use both repositories by including them both in my `build.gradle` in my `android` directory:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is an adjustment to @MHDante's answer - instead of replacing one with the other, you can use both!

Answer (score 0):

I was heaving the same/similar problem:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'X'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
>        Required by:
>            :X:unspecified
>   Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
>   Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]'.
>   Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'. Received status code 401 from server: Authorization Required

But I resolved it by calling synchroise and then rebuilding the project.