# Android Studio Gradle Download Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When I load Android Studio, I get an error

```
Gradle 'HelloWorld' project refresh failed
Error:Could not download artifact 'com.android.tools.build:builder-model:0.12.1:builder-  model.jar': No cached version available for offline mode
```

Not only this but Android Studio takes a long time to load a project; stuck on Gradle Resolve Dependencies.

I am on Windows 8.1 and using JDK 8

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably have Android Studio configured to use Gradle in offline mode, and it's failing because it lacks dependencies that it needs to download. Make sure your computer has internet connectivity, and in Preferences > Gradle > Offline work, make sure that setting is unchecked.

Comment: My Android studio is still stuck on Gradle： Configure project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621678/android-studio-stuck-when-creating-new-project-on-gradle-configure-project-or-g

Answer (score 1):

**For Android Studio 3.3.2** - 
Open File > Settings > Gradle > (unchecked) offline work on Global Gradle Setting.
Make sure that you have internet connection and try to sync your project more (or File > Sync project with gradle files).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is -
click file > project structure > Gradle Setting >
now check if your "Gradle user Home" field is empty if it is . then enter the path of your gradle.

your gradle should be stored in
C > users > .gradle
copy the path and enter it here and now click on gradle build button on top right in your android studio.