# Infinitely start of android studio (Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app:_debugCompile')

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I installed Android studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 and created new Project. When I create a new project Android Studio infinitely sits with below message:

> **Gradle: Resolve dependencies':app:_debugCompile'**

How do I understand what problem is?

[image]

Comment: Let you wait till gradle sync complete it's process.

Comment: 30 minutes is not a lot for an empty project?

Comment: Try restarting android studio if not done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648966/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolving-dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run Android Studio, and before you create new project, go to the settings. To do that go to the Configure button (bottom right) and select Settings. Than Settings screen appears. Go to Appereance & Behavior -> System Settings ->HTTP Proxy
[Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6pHx.jpg)

Click OK and try to create new project. There will be few screen to create new project. Click Next and Finish. Than on system ask you about proxy settings. Set checkbox to Enable HTTPS Proxy

[HTTPS Proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCbD1.jpg)

You can set "Do not show this dialog in the future".

It should work!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue while one of my external dependencies site drop. Check if all your external dependencies are accessible.