# Gradle resolve dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

When I start the project for first time it shows gradle resolve dependencies'app:compile'.

I have tried restarting the project and building it again

Comment: can you post your logcat also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio stuck on gradle resolving dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648966/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolving-dependencies)