# Android Studio stucks at "Gradle: Resolve Dependencies ':app:_debugUnitTestApk'"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm on a proxy network and I've added proxy dependence at few places like: 
'Appearance & Behaviour -> System Setting -> HTTP Proxy'  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imkLt.png)
'gradle.properties'

Gradle sync is stuck at "Gradle: Resolve Dependencies ':app:_debugUnitTestApk'  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BglFy.png)

I am a newbie and I've installed AS just yesterday.

Update1:

1. I've tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36652139/4381961 and the problem persists.
2. I want to add that problem shouldn't be with proxy (since I've set it up already). Although its possible that I might have missed something.
3. I am on MacOs Sierra

Comment: your answer is here [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648966/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolving-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for writing back. I've checked that answer before and have configured AS to use proxy. A friend of mine who is helping me to setup AS has the same configuration and his gradle is syncing properly.

Comment: I've also tried this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36652139/4381961. And the AS again gets stuck at Gradle: Resolve Dependencies ':app:_debugUnitTestApk'.

Comment: Any AntiVirus or something like installed in your Mac.

Comment: No antivirus in Mac.

Comment: Dear @DkThakur, thank you so much! I can cry for this answer then 13 hours research! AVG had caused the problem and solved now!

Comment: @shal8mani Did you solve the issue, I tried all the options in the links provided here but not able to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

restart your PC clean the project and rebuild it. 
or make new project copy the whole project files and paste it to new one.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've just done exactly what you've asked me to do and the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the antivirus can solve the problem in Windows 7.